# How to set qss style for two different tab bars of two QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

Is there any way to set two different qss style rules for two QTabWidgets tabs.
I can set style rule for all tab like this:

```
QTabBar::tab {...}
```

But it will set the stye for all tab bars of QTabWidgets

How to set QTabBar tab style for certain instance of QTabWidget?

Comment: You use the `setStyleSheet()` on wich object ?

Comment: Oh, thanks. I set style for entire app. I foolishly forgot I can do that for any object

Comment: yes you can do that on each object but you can also use the object name as an ID, like `QTabWidget#myobjname { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **QObject::setObjectName(const QString &name)** function to give every QTabWidget a different name and then set the style for a particular QTabWidget using its name:

```
QTabWidget#tabname {...}
```

Alternatively you can do the same on the code side without using the **setObjectName()** function but setting the stylesheet directly to the widget itself like this:

```
ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tab is the first or the last, you can do this:

The first tab:

```
QTabBar::tab:first
{
    color: blue;
}
```

The last tab:

```
QTabBar::tab:last
{
    color: red;
}
```

Any tab that's not the last (also works for first):

```
QTabBar::tab:!last
{
    color: orange;
}
```